# syntax error near unexpected token ( in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm playing with lua, using the following link: https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html and got confused about this syntax error. 
So, the file foo.lua is as the following:

```
function foo (x)
        print(x)
end
```

Then,

```
~$ f = loadfile("foo.lua")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't run Lua code from the Bash shell prompt. You need to start the Lua interpreter.

Comment: Maybe in a distant future Lua will be integrated in bash :-)